# devtools.core not found after including cljs-ajax

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, figwheel, cljs-ajax

I've set up a new Reagent project with `lein new reagent-frontend serverless-todo-front-cljs`

After I include cljs-ajax and run `lein figwheel` I get an error:

```
No such namespace: devtools.core, could not locate devtools/core.cljs, devtools/core.cljc, or JavaScript source providing "devtools.core"
```

The install is fresh the only change I have made is to include cljs-ajax in project.clj, like this:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
             [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.238"]
             [reagent "0.8.0"]
             [cljs-ajax "0.7.3"]]
```

Any tips on how to solve or how to even attempt to debug this are highly appreciated. I have already tried deleting the entire project and creating a new one with a different name.

Comment: FWIW I followed the steps you provided and did not see the problem.

Comment: can you post a github repo perhaps?

Comment: I seemed to get past this problem by recreating the project with a different name.My first attempt was named "serverless-todo-front-cljs". Even after deleting the entire directory, rebooting, and then recreating the procject with the same name didn't fix the problem. Created another project with name "todo-front-cs" and it worked just fine. Weird stuff. And literally the only change in both was adding cljs-ajax as a dependency.

Comment: @TimothyPratley thank you for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: I am glad it worked for you the second time. Is it possible that in the 'serverless-toto-front-cljs' project the target directory remained in place? If you do a `lein clean` that might remove some left over problem. Not sure what else to try... but sounds like the new project works so great :)

Comment: I also tried but failed to repro.

Comment: Seems like having "cljs" in the project name causes something to break. Using a different computer I was able to reproduce this. Project named "todo-front" works fine, but "todo-front-cljs" gives the error described, but only after including cljs-ajax as a dependency.

Comment: I tried with your revised repro instructions and failed to repro.